# Should a 12Factor App persist config in the DB?

Tags: design, configuration-management

The [12factor](http://12factor.net/) approach to config is

> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables...they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.

I've worked on many (rails) projects where configuration items like the boundary box for a map or the name of a client, were stored in a database table, usually named something like `settings` or `system_config`.  Some projects had 1 column per configuration setting, others 1 row per configuration setting

These then get accessed by DB calls and treated in-app as records.  Is this a violation of the 12factor description?  It feels like it is, since it's not an environment variable and they aren't language agnostic.  I know there are alternatives which use ENV, such as figaro and dotenv, but is the DB solution *wrong* or just another option?

Comment: It's clearly not in compliance with 12factor. Is that really what you're asking, or are you trying to poll for opinions on whether it's OK to deviate from what 12factor says? (Such a question would probably be closed as opinion-based.) For whatever it's worth, I find their rationale questionable.

Comment: It is what I'm asking- did a more senior architect do it wrong or did I misunderstand the suggestion?  It sounds like you're answering that question in your first sentence...

Comment: You answered the question yourself with the text you quoted. Anyways, define "do it wrong". Why is 12factor "right" *a priori*?